# Undefined when calling rootNode.childElements?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am puzzled - my rootNode has a value, be it dom.html or Document, however the childElements is always undefined. Everything that ever comes back is undefined.

[image: As you can see, root is defined]

[image: While child elements is not]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element[element]` should be `elements[element]` at each occurrence.